# Is it possible to pass string and integer values together to case in the switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have let's say two answers one is string and another an integer trying to use switch with logical operators. Here is what I have and when I provide a number **1** it is not outputting related answer. Is there any way to accomplish that ?

How can accept an answer if it is given as a string or integer ?

I forgot to add this line of code

```
  var test = prompt('your fav number ?');
user.toUpperCase();

    switch(test) {
case  'one', 1:
    var numberSentence = 'one';
    var numbernumber = 1;
    if(numberSentence === 'one' && numbernumber === 1) {
        console.log('you got the answer') ; 
    }else {
        console.log('pls try again');
    }
    break;
case 'two':
    var twoSentence = 'two';
    var twoNumber = 2;
    if (twoSentence === 'two' || twoNumber === 2 ){
        console.log('Cool you got it right');
    }else {
        console.log('do u want try again?');    
    }
    console.log('it is two awesome' );
    break;
case 'seven':
    console.log('seven is my fav number as well ');
    break;
default:
console.log('you could have at least said smth.');
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you setting the variables and then immediately testing if they have those same values? What does that have to do with whether the user got it right?

Comment: if you ask a number answer can be given as a string or as a number ... I want to give approval for both answer whether it is string or integer

Comment: I believe you're looking for `case "1": case "one": …`, but I really cannot tell from your question.

Comment: How can accept an answer if it is given as a string or integer ?

Comment: @code4life Are you aware of that your `if`s will always evaluate to true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put two values in a single `case` statement, but you can make use of fall-through. And if you're getting user input, it will always be a string, even if they type a number, so you should put it in quotes.

```js
test = prompt("Please type a number");
switch (test) {
  case "1":
  case "one":
    alert("That's the first number");
    break;
  case "2":
  case "two":
    alert("Second place isn't as good");
    break;
  case "3":
  case "three":
    alert("Three is a magic number");
    break;
  default:
    alert("I don't know that number");
}
```

When a `case` doesn't end with `break`, it simply continues with the next case. This allows you to handle multiple cases with the same code.

Comment: Still I can't get expected answer ... despite making given changes

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, your assignments and `if` statements don't make sense. That's a separate issue from using `switch`.

Comment: How can I output the same message if the user gives me a number as a string or as a number

Comment: Put the number in quotes, since user input is always a string.